# Jenkins job auto-triggering when code commit on SVN repo using POST COMMIT hook

Tags: jenkins, svn

I am trying to implement CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins , docker and Ansible. I am using SVN code repository for my version control system. For deployment and SVN code repo, I am using AWS EC2. Deployment and code repo is in separate VM.

**My Requirement**

When I am committing my code into SVN repository , I need to trigger one Jenkins Job. That job will call a ansible playbook.Later it will build project, build Docker image and deploy into EC2. So for any change to my SVN code repository, I need to build Jenkins job.

**My Current Attempt**

I added the following script in post-commit.tmpl file under $repo/hooks folder.

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
UUID=`svnlook uuid $REPOS`
/usr/bin/wget \
  --header "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" \
  --post-data "`svnlook changed --revision $REV $REPOS`" \
  --output-document "-" \
  --timeout=2 \
  http://server/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=$REV
```

The following is the screenshot

[image]

And checked the "Poll SCM option in Jenkins Job":

[image]

**NB:** I am not looking minute/hours/week schedule to pull from repo. Instead of that, I am looking when there is a code change, then I need to build  Jenkins project. So I did not add any schedule.

But still I am not getting the latest code in Jenkins. How can I find out the issue related with my configuration?

**Updated post-commit.tmpl file**

[image]

Comment: Do you have  "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" security option enabled? And also have you checked Jenkins log if there is maybe an error logged?

Comment: You can check it under ManageJenkins - > ConfigureGlobalSecurity and look for Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits checkbox. I think from Jenkins 2.x this option is enabled by default.

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487563/github-webhook-url-config-issue-how-to-fix-it/49441937#49441937

Comment: @RaoslawSzamszur - Yes , its already checked that option in configure global security.

Comment: @rohitthomas - thank you for response. I will check and read about this link that you given here.

Comment: @rohitthomas - There only mentioning about the Github.I am here using subversion. No options for subversion. Is there anything need to do to hit the svn hook on jenkins side ? I only added the config in /hooks/post-commit.tmpl file and checked the Poll SCM in Jenkins.Is there any separate pluggin need to add?

Comment: @Jacob Ignore the GitHUB keyword and try the scenarios ...2 question that is present in that link: is Jenkins run locally ?? and do you have a proxy ??

Comment: `# Every 2 minutes
H/2 * * * *` Add this piece in the POLL SCM and do a check in and wait for 2 mins... if it doesn't happen most probably you are running it locally

Comment: @rohitthomas - Thank you for your response. I checked with every 2 minutes. Its properly working. I cross checked with in every minute also. I am getting that also successfully.And I am not using any proxy.

Comment: @Jacob you will have to look into the Logs(Manage Jenkins-->System logs) Do a commit and observe if a log is captured mostly it wont. If that's the case then you will have to change the Script `post-commit.tmp`

Comment: @Jacob can you modify the `post-commit.tmp` to do the following `SET REPOS=%1
SET REV=%2
wget http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/my_project/build` This should trigger the specific job(my_project) .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183528/discussion-between-jacob-and-rohit-thomas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made lot attempt to resolve this problem by using guidance from answers. Finally I got the actual issue that I was facing. I added the post-commit script in the file "post-commit.tmpl". This file defaulty I got when I created my SVN repository. Instead of adding the "post-commit.tmpl" need to create file just "post-commit". It resolved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Like @bahrep said its hard to troubleshoot issues like this, but my guess is that your post-commit hook doesn't work because of "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" Jenkins security option (You've confirmed it's enabled).

[From Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin#SubversionPlugin-Windowsspecificpostcommithook):

> If your Jenkins uses the "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits"
>   security option, the above request will be rejected with 403 errors
>   ("No valid crumb was included"). The crumb needed in this request can
>   be obtained from the URL http://server/crumbIssuer/api/xml (or
>   /api/json). This can be included in the wget call above with something
>   like this:

```
--header `wget -q --output-document - \
  'http://server/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)'`
```

The easiest way to confirm if this security option causes the problem to would be to disable it and try if post-commit hook will work. If yes enable again and try to configure hook with crumb. (In the end, you want to have things secure :) )

And also make sure that Jenkins has enabled anonymous read access:

> For this to work, your Jenkins has to allow anonymous read access
>   (specifically, "Job > Read" access) to the system. If access control
>   to your Jenkins is more restrictive, you may need to specify the
>   username and password, depending on how your authentication is
>   configured.

[image]

#### Edit

I think the problems occur because you haven't provided Jenkins instance address. In your webhook example you have:

```
http://server/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=$REV
```

You should change `server` to your Jenkins instance address (Ip, domain or ip and port. It depends on your configuration.).

```
http://yourjenkins.com/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=$REV

http://<IP>:<Port>/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=$REV

http://<IP>/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=$REV
```

Or if you run everything locally (including svn repo):

```
http://localhost:8080/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=$REV
```

But remember to have:

- "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" security option disabled (You will create webhook to work with this option later, now we want to find the root cause)
- "allow anonymous read access" security option enabled

I think the hook script works just fine but it's being sent to nowhere. This can be easily checked by logging your hook script. Just add at the end of hook:

```bash
echo "`$REPOS` change to revision `$REV` triggered @ `date`" >> ${REPOS}/post-commit-hook.log
```

and look if after commit log file was created. If yes it means the `wget` request is being sent incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I disabled  the "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" option and checked. Then also its not working. I think this is not the proper reason (Security related).

Comment: @Jacob probably issue occurs before communicating with Jenkins, but still, this security option would stop your post hook. Now back to debugging, can your Jenkins job poll SCM at all (try entering any schedule value ex.: `H/5 * * * *`)  This will tell if the problem is with communication or your post-hook. Also you've mentioned that code is in separate VM, can your EC2 instance talk with this VM at all? (Maybe you forgot to set ALC for this AWS instance)

Comment: Yes sir. I already tried and confirmed this.  H/2 * * * * working. And also tried with every minute also. That also working. I am able to see my modified code in jenkins workspace. For every minute and every 2 minute , its working. Problem is related with post-hook.

Comment: @Jacob do you have enabled "Allow anonymous read access" option (I've added a screenshot in edit)? This was also mentioned in Wiki that is necessary in order to post-commit hook to work.

Comment: I checked the option "Allow anonymous read access " that you given like in screenshot. But that also not working.

Comment: @Jacob Recently I was thinking about other possible solutions, and I have found an issue with your post-commit hook. Please look at Edit. I hope this will resolve this :)

Comment: I modified the post-commit.tmpl file according to your edit for adding IP address of Jenkins. But still not building the job when modifying the svn repo. I added the screenshot for updated post-commit file above. Can you please check the screenshot above added with updation . I am also disabled "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits". And enabled "allow anonymous read access".

Comment: Have you checked my updated screenshot for your edit?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to troubleshoot this problem without seeing actual errors and the log. However, one of the possible reasons is that your SVN server requires authentication. You should specify a correct username and password and make sure that this user account has Read permissions to the SVN repository.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes. I already checked the user permission. When I am manually running ansible playbook its checkouting (I added maven module using ansible playbook for checkouting). Also In my local editor also its checkouting. After I added the configuration in hooks, When I am commiting , my jenkins job not building. Within Jenkins I am calling the playbook for CI/CD pipeline inclusing the svn checkout stage. Manually its checkout is working. Only problem is related with Hooks.

Answer (score 0):

there is an easier way ...by simply defining the schedule for the trigger:

[image: jenkins screenshot]

or use `trigger builds remotely`, if wanting a push instead of a pull solution, which requires posting to `https://username:api-token@JENKINS_URL/job/Example/build`, with a predefined API token; [authenticating scripted clients](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients) explains it. building only on changes suggested, because everything else would unnecessarily cost processing power (which equals money).